# Creating bowling game. Ball shape is modified when chaging X-axis

Tags: c++, eclipse, opengl, glut

I am creating a bowling game using Eclipse C++ in Opengl.

I have created cones using **glutSolidCone()** and the ball using **glutSolidSphere()**

When ball's co-ordinates are `GLfloat ball[] = {/* X */ 0.0f, /* Y */-2.0f, /* Z */ -6.0f, /*sphere*/ 0.9f, 50.0, 50.0 };`

and the code for ball is `glTranslated(ball[0], ball[1], ball[2]);`

`glutSolidSphere(ball[3], ball[4], ball[5]);` it looks like [image: ball looks good]

but when I change ball's X-axis to `GLfloat ball[] = {/* X */ -5.0f, /* Y */ -2.0f, /* Z */ -6.0f, /*sphere*/ 0.9f, 50.0, 50.0 };` it looks like [image: not showing well]

My code for **glutReshapeFunc()** is as below: -

```
static void resize(int width, int height) {
    const float ar = (float) width / (float) height;

    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glFrustum(-ar, ar, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 100.0);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}
```

Why bowl's shape is modified when I change its X value? How to retain it same when the ball was in center?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Kevin I am asking that why the bowl's shape is modified in the second image when I change the X value of the ball.

Comment: That is called perspective, you probably have a different field of view than you expected.

Comment: Actually I am coding using OpenGL for first time, after a lot of head-ache, I have done this and reached this problem then. Can you suggest any solution/logic/code?

Comment: I have put such effort and a guy just voted down me... Huhhhh

Answer (score 1):

> Why bowl's shape is modified when I change its X value?

What you see is the perspective distortion applied on the ball.

> How to retain it same when the ball was in center?

Use a longer "lens", i.e. narrower field of view to reduce the perspective distortion. You can do this by using `glFrustum`, or you use some helper function like `gluPerspective` which effectively does just this:

```
void gluPerspective(
    float fovyInDegrees,
    float aspectRatio,
    float znear,
    float zfar)
{
    float ymax, xmax;
    float temp, temp2, temp3, temp4;
    ymax = znear * tanf(fovyInDegrees * M_PI / 360.0);
    xmax = ymax * aspectRatio;
    glFrustum(-xmax, xmax, -ymax, ymax, znear, zfar);
}
```

Note that there will always be some distortion toward the view's edges in a affine perspective.